# I heard some say "I took a piss"

Tags: grammar

Is it a wrong or right English to say
**I took a piss**
Indicating that she went to urinate. 
But I was thinking the right way to put it should be 
***I took a pee***
Can I have a better way to put this other than `I went to urinate`.

Comment: Related: [peeing vs pissing](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9938/peeing-versus-pissing-versus-taking-a-pee); also [the verbs pee and piss](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76181/whats-the-difference-between-verbs-pee-and-piss)

Comment: On a kind of related note: "he's taking **a** piss" = "he's urinating"; "he's taking **the** piss" = "he's making fun (joke) of *something*" (BrE)

Answer (score 3):

In British English, to take a pee is a little more polite than take a piss. You could ask your child in public "do you need to take a pee?" and it would be inoffensive to other adults nearby. "Do you need to take a piss?" would be shocking. Piss is the equivalent of shit. Pee is the equivalent of poo.

Answer (score 0):

If by "better" you mean in a more euphemistic way, then yes:

I had to go number one.

OR:

I went number one.

go number one = to urinate

go number two = to defecate

Keep in mind that both connote childishness, but I think it's good enough if you're with friends. If you want to be formal, I'd recommend saying:

I went to the bathroom.

Taking a piss is correct English by the way:

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+piss

Comment: If any adult said " I have to go #1" and there were no children around, I would think them very odd.  If you can't say, "I need to pee" just say "excuse me, I'll be right back".

Comment: This is at best archaic. I've got family in US and am myself from the UK. Never heard this used seriously since I was a child. For no reason I can discern "pee" is somehow more polite than "piss".

Comment: iLove Sophie - does this mean that it's more formal to take a bath, rather than just to void one's bladder?

Comment: @djna Pee came later as a euphemistic abbreviation for piss according to etymology online http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pee.

Comment: thanks colleen, I'd seen it as a simple synonym, but you're right it's more euphemistic and hence more "polite".

Comment: @P.E.Dant I'm not sure if you meant this seriously. You make it sound like the two denoted the same thing. Actually, I think the medical term is perhaps just voiding (reference: http://www.diabetesselfmanagement.com/managing-diabetes/complications-prevention/resolving-diabetes-related-bladder-problems/ and http://www.valeofyorkccg.nhs.uk/rss/index.php?id=lower-urinary-tract-symptoms-in-men-luts ). Anyway, taking/having a bath have no particular connotations for me, while voiding screams that it's a medical term.

Comment: @djna You mean going No. 1 or 2 are archaic? Because I could've sworn that I have heard them used by a few characters in a few series.

Comment: @iLoveSophie Not so seriously, no. Poking fun at the common euphemism which I know has puzzled more than one beginning student of English. When a dining companion announced that she was going to the bathroom, one such student once turned to me and said: _Elle peut laver seulement ses mains, non?_